# Differences how many and whatever in the following context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, questions

What is the difference between the following sentences.

> 1.Tell me **how many** books you have.
>
> 2.Tell me **whatever** books you have.

Comment: In what situation are you saying this: *Tell me whatever books you have.* Normally you would say: *Tell me what books you have.* Also do you realize that **how many** is asking for the number,  not the identity of the books. So basically **how many** is a different question than **what**.

Comment: What do you think the difference is.  How would you answer these questions?  You will make your question better if you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

- how many

This asks for the number.

> Alice: **How many** books do you have?
>
> Bob: I have about twenty or thirty books.

- what

This asks to identify the specific object or objects.

> Alice: **What** books do you have?
>
> Bob: Mostly fantasy and science fiction.

- whatever, whichever

This invites the listener to identify a particular object. Whatever implies that you want to identify one object within a larger set of objects:

> Alice: Show me a book.
>
> Bob: Lets see... which one?
>
> Alice: **Whatever** book is your favorite.

Whichever implies that you want to identify one object within a smaller set of objects:

> Alice: Hand me that book.
>
> Bob: Which book?
>
> Alice: **Whichever** book you are not reading.

- whatsoever

This sounds similar to whatever but is usually used to emphasize a negative.

> Alice: How many books do you have, Charlie?
>
> Charlie: I have no books **whatsoever**.

Note that there is no **whichsoever**.